# Why COALESCE() does not work?

Tags: mysql, sum

Here is my query:

```
select COALESCE(t1.col1, 0) from table1 t1 where table2.id = t1.col2
```

So, The output is sometimes *empty*. Why? I used of `COALESCE()` just because if the result is empty it puts `0` instead. How can I fix it?

**Note:** `COALESCE()` works in this query as well:

```
select COALESCE(sum(t1.col1), 0) from table1 t1 where table2.id = t1.col2
```

---

**Edit:** Actually I want to say: If there is no result *(no row founded)* returns `0`.

Comment: I also tried `IFNULL(t1.col1, 0)` and did not work too.

Comment: coalesce returns the first non-NULL value, not first non-empty value.  Also, table2 is mentioned in where clause, but not in table list.  I would expect this to give an error.

Comment: Are you sure that t1.col1 is NULL and not just an empty (zero-length) string.  They aren't the same and COALESCE / ISNULL only functions as you're expecting with the former.

Comment: Try using CASE WHEN t1.col1 = "" THEN 0 ELSE t1.col1 END

Comment: There is no table2 here.

Comment: There is no table2 here

Comment: @Strawberry yes there is not, I just wrote a sub-query. I don't think full query is needed.

Comment: @Strawberry well, you suppose the query is like this: `select COALESCE(t1.col1, 0) from table1 t1 where id = 10;`. And `id = 10` does not exist in database. So how can I get `0`?

Comment: Outer join the table to itself on that criterion

Comment: @Strawberry eem, I don't know, can you please write a short answer for me? BTW, in your opinion, using `sum()` is not faster than using `outer join`? Because as I mentioned in the question, when I use `sum()` the result will be what I want.

Comment: COALESCE() works perfectly here. The difference between both queries is not COALESCE but SUM. This second query is an aggregate and works in a totally different way.

Comment: Or you can use CASE. If you want an example (from me anyway) then you'd need to provide representative data and a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry No thanks. My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is your query:

```
select COALESCE(t1.col1, 0)
from table1 t1
where id = 10;
```

Then it will not return any rows when there is no match.  If you know you want one row, you can use aggregation:

```
select COALESCE(MAX(t1.col1), 0)
from table1 t1
where id = 10;
```

This is guaranteed to return one row and it won't be `NULL`.  Another approach uses `union all`:

```
select t1.col1
from table1 t1
where id = 10
union all
select 0
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 where id = 10);
```

Or, another way:

```
select coalesce((select col1 from table1 where id = 10),
                0)
```

In this context, the lack of row is turned into a scalar `NULL` value, so `COALESCE()` can work on that.

As a note:  `COALESCE()` works fine.  You need to realize that it works on *column values*.  It cannot conjure a row when none are being returned.

Comment: Perfect...! This answer is exactly what I wanted. +1